# Modifying css with javascript quickly flashes on screen then returns to original (help)

Tags: javascript, css

A little hard to explain but here it is, I changed some css with javascript and when i run it in my web browser it appears and then quickly disappears back to the original css. In other words my changed css value from javascript doesn't stay!

CSS:

```
#login_temp{
width: 350px;
height:150px;
background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -175px;
margin-top: -150px;
border-radius: 2px;
box-shadow: 0px 30px 40px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
```

}

HTML:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick = dog(); value="Login" />
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function dog(){
document.getElementById("login_temp").style.background = "black";
}
```

Comment: Since it's a submit button, the form gets submitted, and that reloads the page.

Answer (score 1):

You give a type of 'submit' to input element, so when you click the button, it invoke the dog() function and then do a submit action. If you did not set action attribute of the wrap form element, the page will reload itself by default.

You can just remove type='submit' to prevent this happen, or you can use event.preventDefault() to avoid the default action happens.

Answer (score 0):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEQzRp

Try by putting return false on the onclick attribute.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick = "dog(); return false" value="Login" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is correct - it will change the submit button state but also as it's also a submit page the page is being submitted / refreshed so the original CSS styles will take over again as if it was the first visit.